# Any idea why setting the background in custom notification using an attribute resource crashes?

Tags: android, android-notifications, remoteview

I'm trying to set the background color of a custom notification main layout to a color depending of the selected theme:

```
 android:background="?attr/actionbar_background"
```

It makes the app crashes. If I replace it with a 'fixed' color it works fine:

```
 android:background="@color/actionbar_background_back"
```

attr/actionbar_background is correctly defined because I'm using it in other layouts and it works fine

Here's the stacktrace I'm getting:

```
android.app.RemoteServiceException: Bad notification posted from package com.xxx.yyy: Couldn't expand RemoteViews for: StatusBarNotification(pkg=com.xxx.yyy user=UserHandle{0} id=1000001 tag=null score=10 key=0|com.xxx.yyy|1000001|null|10582: Notification(pri=1 contentView=com.xxx.yyy/0x7f03003f vibrate=null sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x62 color=0x00000000 category=transport vis=PUBLIC))
```

Is it an Android limitation ?

Comment: ?attr/actionbar_background is defined correctly, but are you using a style that has it defined?

Comment: this style is working fine anywhere else in the app. It just looks like this cannot work when used in a RemoteViews which seems strange